# Is it true that functional languages are intrinsically hard to make interface with non functional languages

Tags: functional-programming, calling-convention

I was told this to be the case by someone but never quite understood why and didn't believe it. Doing a check of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface it seems to be the case. Is this true? And if so why?

Comment: FFI refers to a more common description of a function, which is just block of code that you can call with arguments and get a result of. Functional programming doesn't just mean 'using functions' but it as a lot of additional implications. Functions should be pure (side-effect free) and there's other properties that make a language 'functional'. If you are curious about this, I would learn more about what functional programming and lambda calculus is.

Comment: I know what a functional language is. I was just wondering if it is actually true that it is hard to make a functional programming language interface with another language, like how python interfaces with C.

Comment: I think this question is too broadly scoped to belong on Stack Overflow. I echo Evert in suggesting doing more research and then asking a more specific question.

Comment: I think 100% pure functional language can by its definition not interface *at all* with the outside world, including reading files, using network or accept user input. I can only guess what your co-worker meant (there's not a lot of detail here), but this is something that comes to mind.

Comment: The question has a simple scope, is it more difficult to have FFI in a functional language. I know some exist, but is it true that it is harder? And if so why? The question has such a small scope in fact that i would take "no" as a complete answer!

Comment: Yes pure functional languages cannot interface with the outside world, but many real life functional langues do and it is those that I am interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A functional programming language is simply one which encourages the treatment of functions as values in their own right. This is orthogonal to whether it integrates well with other languages. Indeed, Clojure, Scala, and F# are designed to interoperate with Java, Java (again), and C# respectively.

It might take some work to adapt the API to the idioms of the target language. But this issue isn't unique to functional languages—most C interfaces won't look great as-is in Python either! And this work is optional: the Haskell `network` package is but a thin wrapper around Berkeley sockets, yet people are more than happy to use it.

> I think 100% pure functional language can by its definition not interface at all with the outside world

That's a common misconception.

A pure functional language does not *ban* side effects; it *annotates* them—whether it be through an `IO` monad (Haskell), linear types (Mercury), or algebraic effects (Idris). In such a language, calling a foreign function would feel no different to any other I/O operation.

Moreover, if the programmer knows that the foreign function is pure (e.g. an LAPACK routine) then they can overrule the compiler and declare it as such. In Haskell, this can be done by omitting `IO` from the function's signature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess the person who told me it was hard to do was misinformed, which is strange because he was pretty qualified.